# How to find how many pair numbers exists inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, std-pair

I need to find how many pairs are inside my array.
Input 
`$n= 9` (quantity of numbers)
`$arr = [10, 20, 20 ,10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];`

- There are 4 number 10s = so 2 pairs of 10
- There are 3 number 20s = so 1 pair of 20
- 30 and 50 don't repeat and the other 20 (about) that doesn't have a pair

The result should be as follows: 
2 (pairs of 10) + (1 pair of 20) = 3 pairs

I am trying to compare each number and if there is a match(pair) I increment my variable, after that, I divide my incremented var by 2 and get the entire part of the division.

```
function pairs($n, $ar) {

    $i; 
    $j; 
    $pair = 0;
    $aux = 0;

     for($i = 0; $i < $n-1; $i++){  
        if($ar[$i] == $ar[$i + 1])
        {
           $aux++;
        } 
        $pair += intval(($aux / 2),10);
    }   
    return $pair;     
}
```

This input
`$n = 9`
`$ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];`

Should give me 3 as a result, but I'm getting 5 instead

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 3):

Count the number of values, map a function that returns the rounded down count divided by 2 (pair):

```
$result = array_map(function($v) { return floor($v / 2); }, array_count_values($arr));
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [10] => 2
    [20] => 1
    [30] => 0
    [50] => 0
)
```

To get the sum `3`, just sum:

```
$sum = array_sum(array_map(function($v) { return floor($v / 2); }, array_count_values($arr)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly! I'm not used to using array_map yet! So is there a way to accomplish that using normal loops ( like for and while)?
Just asking out of curiosity cuz your solution worked just fine!

Comment: @DebborahCamargo isn't that exactly what my answer is?

Answer (score 2):

A very *conservative approach* is the following.
It sorts the array and then looks for duplicate values by checking if the previous value is the same. If so, it resets the previous value and continues.

```
$n= 9;
$arr = [10, 20, 20 ,10, 10, 60, 30, 50, 10, 20];

function pairs($n, $ar) 
{

    $cnt = 0;
    $prevVal = 0;
    asort($ar,true);
    foreach ($ar as $key => $val)
    {
        if ($val == $prevVal)
        {
            $cnt++;
            $prevVal = 0;
        } else      
            $prevVal = $val;
    }
    return $cnt;     
}

var_dump(pairs($n, $arr));
```

It outputs the correct value of `3`.

Of course, this doesn't work if the array can have `0` as a value. In this specific case you'd have to use another way to indicate "not the same"; maybe an option type or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_count_values and then loop the array and return the floor of the count/2.

```
$arr = [10 ,20 ,20 ,10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20];

$counts = array_count_values($arr);

foreach($counts as $val => &$count){
    $count = floor($count/2);
}

var_dump($counts);


/*
array(4) {
  [10]=>
  float(2)
  [20]=>
  float(1)
  [30]=>
  float(0)
  [50]=>
  &float(0)
}
*/
```

Comment: Thanks man! 

I also tried this one now and it worked too ( In javascript)
function sockMerchant(n, ar) {
    var pair = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
        var aux = 1;
        if (ar[i] !== 0) {
            for (var j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (ar[i] == ar[j]) {
                    ar[j] = 0;
                    aux++;
                }

            }
            ar[i] = 0;
            pair += Math.floor(aux / 2);
        }
        
    }
    return pair;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
This is work for me.

```
<?php
$n = 9;
$arr = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 60, 30, 50, 10, 20];

function pair($n, $arr)
{
    sort($arr);
    $count = 0;
    for ($i = 0;$i < $n;$i++)
    {

        for ($j = $i + 1;$j < $n;$j++)
        {

            if ($arr[$i] == $arr[$j])
            {

                $i = $i + 2;
                $j = $j + 1;
                $count++;

            }
        }
    }

    echo $count;
}

pair($n, $arr);

?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
asort($array);
$array = array_count_values($array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: Why sort the array? Either way it's only a partial solution

Comment: add description/reference